# Odd result using allowframebreaks in beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I am trying to break a long bibliography in `beamer` using the [\allow framebreaks] option. I am using the [`beamerthemelumc`](https://git.lumc.nl/j.f.j.laros/presentation/blob/5dc55db7bd0e1be6f32c156c0dc3908a8e29e394/beamerthemelumc.sty). It is splitting the bibliography, but there are odd parentheses from the second frame of the bibliography. How to remove them? Below is my codes.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{lumc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathrsfs}

\title{}
\providecommand{\myConference}{}
\providecommand{\myDate}{}
\author{}
\providecommand{\myGroup}{}
\providecommand{\myDepartment}{}
\providecommand{\myCenter}{}
\providecommand{\lastCenterLogo}{}
\providecommand{\lastRightLogo}{}

\begin{document}
    \section{References}
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \begin{thebibliography}{00}\Large
            \bibitem{a} \textbf{a}
            \bibitem{b} \textbf{b}
            \bibitem{c} \textbf{c}
            \bibitem{d} \textbf{d}
            \bibitem{e} \textbf{e}
            \bibitem{f} \textbf{f}
            \bibitem{g} \textbf{g}
            \bibitem{h} \textbf{h}
            \bibitem{i} \textbf{i}
            \bibitem{j} \textbf{j}
            \bibitem{k} \textbf{k}
        \end{thebibliography}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result is something like this. See the second frame.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion: That's really a terrible written theme! Do you have to use it?

However your problem is solvable. Replace the following lines in the `.sty` file

```
% Put a frame title on the slide.
\renewcommand{\frametitle}[1]{
  {\textbf{#1}}
  \bigskip

}
```

by the beamer way of controlling things:

```
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}
```

I ignored the `\bigskip` for now, because I could not see a difference without it. But in case the spacing will be wrong somewhere, one could simply add it to the frametitle template. Please have a look, if you some difference somewhere.

[image]

Comment: I see that your frametitle is on the top of the blue band, but even with the original code that include the `\bigskip` I don't get this result. [Tried with pdflatex from Texlive 2016]

Comment: Thanks you very much. Will try to write a better beamer theme on my own in future.